Wordpress wp-sitemap-posts-post-1.xml getting error on google search console
I have a website. I am trying to submit it's sitemap in google to indexing my post.
I give the /wp-sitemap.xml which is working. But when I am giving the second sitemap /wp-sitemap-posts-post-1.xml it showing Couldn't fetch
But I have the valid sitemap.
My Website sitemap
Post Sitemap of my website
Now how can I solve it?

Appears to be working fine when requested in my browser. Start by checking your server's access and error logs, to see if there is any indication why the request made by Google might get a different response.

How can i do this

If you don't know where to find those files, consult your hoster's documentation, or ask their support.
